# Nested Rows And Sub Rows In Foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Take a look at this pen and code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owPbxZ

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="big-box small-3 columns">
    </div>

  <div class="row">
  <div class="small-box small-4 columns">
    </div>
      <div class="small-box small-4 columns">
    </div>
</div>  
</div>
```

I'm using foundation and I need to make my small grid boxes to the right of the big box look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7RqN.jpg

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Something like this [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/vivekkupadhyay/pen/mwGOGb) ?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay yeah thanks so much!! Embarrassed I couldn't figure that out haha